# Fundamental group acts on universal covering by isometries

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I am reading the proof of Theorem 4.13 in part II in the book Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature of Martin R. Bridson and André Haefliger and in the proof they write "Consider the universal covering $p : \widetilde{X} \to X$ endowed with the induced length metric. Fix $\widetilde{x_{0}} \in \widetilde{X}$ The fundamental group $\pi_{1}\left(X,x_{0}\right)$ acts on $\widetilde{X}$ with $p\left(\widetilde{x_{0}}\right) = x_{0}$ by deck transformations; the action is free and by isometries". Here $X$ is a metric space with metric $d$ and $\widetilde{X}$ is the universal covering of $X$ and the induced length metric is given as

$$
\widetilde{d}\left(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y}\right) = \inf \{l\left(p \circ \gamma\right) : \gamma \ \text{joins} \ \widetilde{x} \ \text{and} \ \widetilde{y}\}.
$$

I managed to proof that the action is free, but I failed to see why the group acts by isometries, I can see that is enough to show that if I have $\gamma$ a closed path in $X$ such that $\gamma\left(0\right) = x_{0}$ and $\widetilde{\gamma}$,$\widetilde{\gamma}'$ two lifts of $\gamma$ starting at different points it is enough to proof

$$
\widetilde{d}\left(\widetilde{\gamma}\left(0\right),\widetilde{\gamma}'\left(0\right)\right) = \widetilde{d}\left(\widetilde{\gamma}\left(1\right),\widetilde{\gamma}'\left(1\right)\right).
$$

I tried creating paths with some concatenations with curves that joins the points in the argument of the metric (if such curves exists, otherwise the equality is easy) but I just ended with useless inequalities, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $g \in \pi_{1}(X,x_0)$ and $a,b \in \widetilde{X}$. We would like to show that $\tilde{d}(a,b) = \tilde{d}(g(a),g(b))$.

Now, if $\gamma$ join $a$ and $b$ then $g(\gamma)$ joins $g(a)$ and $g(b)$. Conversely, if $\gamma$ joins $g(a)$ and $g(b)$, then $g^{-1}(\gamma)$ joins $a$ and $b$. Let us write $\Gamma(a,b)$ for the set of paths from $a$ to $b$, and $\Gamma(g(a),g(b))$ for the set of paths from $g(a)$ to $g(b)$. We see that $\gamma \mapsto g(\gamma)$ is a bijection between $\Gamma(a,b)$ and $\Gamma(g(a),g(b))$.

Next, by the definition of Deck transformations, $p(\gamma) = p(g(\gamma))$ for any path $\gamma$. Thus $p(\Gamma(a,b)) = p(\Gamma(g(a),g(b)))$, i.e. these two sets of paths have the same projection in $X$.

Finally, $\tilde{d}(a,b) = \inf_{\gamma \in p(\Gamma(a,b))}  \ell(\gamma) = \inf_{\gamma \in p(\Gamma(g(a),g(b)))}  \ell(\gamma) = \tilde{d}(g(a),g(b))$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you, I was forgetting to use the deck transformations property